# How to plot horizontal bars / columns / lines on timeseries data with HighStock?

Tags: charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I'd like to plot horizontal bars and/or lines on timeseries data with highstock, however I'm not able to identify the corresponding series type and how to feed the data in?

Is possible? If yes, how?

A screenshot of what I may imagine as outcome:
[image: highstock chart with lines and bars]

Data could be something similar eg:

```
[
  {
    "start": 1610969882000, // epoche time in ms
    "end": 1624016282000,
    "text": "Bar on timeseries",
    "style": "bar",
    "level": 1 // y-Axis height where to show
  },
  {
    "start": 1613648282000, 
    "end": 1618745882000,
    "text": "Line on timeseries",
    "style": "line",
    "level": 8
  }
]
```

I did find [column-range charts](http://jsfiddle.net/ManuelFink/bpd36khq/) which seem to work with line charts, however I struggled overlaying this on a [highstock timeseries chart](https://jsfiddle.net/ManuelFink/ntwpL136/), adding a label on top or making it a line with tooltip. Adding to highstock always ends up throwing an error "Script error."

Thx a lot in advance, I really appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xrange` series type:

```
series: [{
    type: 'xrange',
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o9ks1efd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.xrange